# Pandas Data Reader Issues;

Tags: python, pandas, datareader

so I have something very simple to ask but I can't get my head around it.  I'm trying to import some stock data from yahoo finance, nothing fancy.  I used to do this via:

```
 import pandas.io.data as web
 import pandas as pd
 import datetime

 start=datetime.datetime(2000,1,1)
 end=datetime.date.today()

 SLB=web.DataReader("SLB","yahoo",start,end)
```

Everything used to work lovely like this.  However, I'm well aware of the changes that have taken place.  The import method is now:

```
 from pandas_datareader import data,wb
```

However, using this method, (and I'm still using the same start,end data etc), I receive:

```
   SLB=wb.DataReader("SLB","yahoo",start,end)
   Traceback (most recent call last):

   File "<ipython-input-218-6633f366e2cb>", line 1, in <module>
   SLB=wb.DataReader("SLB","yahoo",start,end)

   AttributeError: module 'pandas_datareader.wb' has no attribute 
   'DataReader'
```

I've had a look online (obviously) for more information, and I've seen in some cases people have put:

```
   SLB=data.DataReader('SLB','yahoo',start,end)
```

which leads to an even longer error altogether regarding issues connecting to the URL.

If anyone has come across this before, or can see errors in my code, It would be great if you could shed some light!

cheers

p.s.

the longer error message I got using:

```
  SLB=data.DataReader("SLB","yahoo",start,end)
```

is:

```
  SLB=data.DataReader("SLB","yahoo",start,end)
  Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-226-0cd57c0d4cbe>", line 1, in <module>
  SLB=data.DataReader("SLB","yahoo",start,end)

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-
  packages\pandas_datareader\data.py", line 116, in DataReader
  retry_count=retry_count, pause=pause,

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-
  packages\pandas_datareader\yahoo\daily.py", line 76, in read
  """ read one data from specified URL """

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-
  packages\pandas_datareader\base.py", line 155, in read
  if isinstance(self.symbols, (compat.string_types, int)):

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-
  packages\pandas_datareader\base.py", line 74, in _read_one_data
  out = self._read_url_as_StringIO(url, params=params)

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-
  packages\pandas_datareader\base.py", line 85, in _read_url_as_StringIO
  response = self._get_response(url, params=params)

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-
  packages\pandas_datareader\base.py", line 120, in _get_response
  raise RemoteDataError('Unable to read URL: {0}'.format(url))

  RemoteDataError: Unable to read URL: 
  http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?
  s=SLB&a=0&b=1&c=2000&d=5&e=16&f=2017&g=d&ignore=.csv
```

Hope this helps a little bit more.

Comment: What is that *even longer error altogether regarding issues connecting to the URL*?

Comment: @JonClements.  Question updated.

Comment: Is the API still actually active? I'm sure in fleeting reading they deprecated some, moved some and removed others...

Comment: @JonClements.  I think you might have a point there.  Just used Google Finance and all data loaded fine, so thanks for the advice!